# Get local date time and time in Django

Tags: python, django

How can I get the local date and time in Django?

I tried this solution. But it works only for the date `now`.

```
from django.utils import timezone

now = timezone.localtime(timezone.now()) #OK
date = timezone.localtime(timezone.date())  #Error
time = timezone.localtime(timezone.time())  #Error
```

Preferably in the same format as for datetime

```
now = datetime.datetime.now() #'2020-04-28 17:57:34.120383'
date = datetime.datetime.now().date() #'2020-04-28
time = datetime.datetime.now().time() #18:12:08.987472
```

Comment: Hi Maddie. Your questions have been noticeably more succinct recently, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Extract the date and time from the local instant object.

```
from django.utils import timezone

now = timezone.localtime(timezone.now())
date = now.date()
time = now.time()
```

Comment: Is there a reason to include `timezone.now()` here?