# Date and Time in Django template

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

I tried this [solution](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#date) and also followed this [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61504680/get-local-date-time-and-time-in-django) But still, it doesn't work.
I import it `from django.utils import timezone` as Timezone library.

My `models.py`

```
from django.db import models
from ckeditor_uploader.fields import RichTextUploadingField
from django.utils import timezone

# Create your models here.
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    body = RichTextUploadingField(blank=True, null=True)
    dop = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Django template

```
{% extends "taskscheduler/base.html" %}
{% block title %}{{ post.title }}{% endblock %}

{% block main %}
<div class="continer homepage">
    <div class="row shadow p-3 mb-5 bg-white rounded">
        <div class="col">
            <h3 class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">{{ post.title }}</h3>
            <small class="badge badge-info">{{ post.dop | date:"F d, Y"}} {{ post.dop | time:"H:i" }}</small><hr/>
            <p class="article-content">{{ post.body|safe }}</p>
        <div class="fb-comments" colorscheme="light" data-href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/p/{{ post.id }}" data-numposts="5" data-width="100%"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

But the result still showing only the date.
[image: Result page]
I want to see the date along with the time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `models.DateField`, try this instead:

```
dop = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```